# ObjectMapper maps Boolean field with "is" prefix to same name field without "is" prefix after some time

Tags: java, lombok, getter-setter, jackson-databind, objectmapper

I have a Boolean field in the request body of an API, named "isSafe". This field is mapped to my Pojo class using ObjectMapper.

If I send "safe" in the request then it fails and I get this error `Unrecognized field \"safe\"`.
But this same request starts getting passed after sometime.

My application is deployed on cloud and I have multiple pods running.
After any deployment/restarts of the application, this request fails (which is expected), but after 1-2 hour, one-by-one pods starts giving success response. Eventually, all the requests start getting successful.

Note: I am aware of the conflicts created by Jackson with "is" prefix name field. But in my case, request starts getting successful after a period of time. This is weird.

My question is that why initially after server restart mapper throws error and after some time doesn't throw error even if I pass "safe" field.

Pojo Class field ( I am using @Data for getter and setter):

```
private Boolean isSafe;
```

ObjectMapper bean:

```
new ObjectMapper()
        .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
        .enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
        .registerModules(new JavaTimeModule(), new Jdk8Module());
```

Initial Analysis: If I add @JsonIgnoreProperties in my Pojo class where this field is defined then it works as expected ("safe" field is ignored). But without this, it behaves in a weird way.

Comment: What is your question?  Are you asking whether you have encountered a bug in Jackson?

Comment: My question is that why initially after server restart mapper throws error and after some time doesn't throw error even if I pass "safe" field.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem and what kind of solution you are looking for.
Are you looking for a way to prevent this from happening? Are you asking if this is a library issue?

Comment: I know how to prevent this behaviour (By adding @JsonProperty)  but I need t0 understand why this is happening.
Why "safe" is throwing error just after server restart, but starts getting mapped to "isSafe" after sometime.